# TYPO3: Remove or edit Header in Backend Module

Tags: php, module, typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I created a Backend Module to configure the extension. The user is now able to type in the e-mail address to which the auto-generated e-mail is going to be sent etc.

Unfortunately, there is a header in the Backend Module which contains a dropdown (`<select>`) with *'Overview'* and *'Create new ModelNameHere'*.

Obviously this isn't needed here, is there a way to edit the options or remove the entire header?

EDIT: Running TYPO3 7.6.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it is helpful to know at least the version number of TYPO3 as e.g. 6.2 is a lot different to 7.6 and 8.

Without knowing your extension's code, check out either the template which can be found in `Resources/Private/` or the controller inside `Classes/Controller/<Domain>Controller`. One of those 2 places should contain the unwanted html.

Comment: I'm very sorry, forgot about that. Edited the question. But that's exactly my problem: Both of them are empty (except the minimum required code). It's the same header the Extension Builder also includes at the very top with a select menu with 'Introduction' and 'Domain Modelling'. It's a method to switch between actions and I need to know how to change these...

Comment: Ahhhhh, nope, you were right. It was located at `Resources/Private/Layouts/Default.html`. Thank you!